# Javascript: Create a multiple item json

Tags: javascript, json

I should create an object like this:

```
var query = {"filters":{"type":"OR","filters":[
   {"type":"EQ","fieldName":"name", "value":"Point_1"},
   {"type":"EQ","fieldName":"name", "value":"Point_2"},
   {"type":"EQ","fieldName":"name", "value":"Point_3"}
]}};
```

Now, the name of values (point_1, point_2, point_3) are inside an array called *points[]*, so I would like to create this object dynamically.

What I've done is this

```
var filt = {filters:[]};
for(var i in points){
  filt.filters.push({"type":"EQ","fieldName":"name","value":points[i]}); 
}
var query = {"filters":{"type":"OR","filters":filt}};
```

but this doesn't work.

May you tell me where I'm wrong?

Comment: What is points? But why not just using `JSON.stringify( query.filters )`?

Comment: @SmaK  `filt` need not to be an object. just create it as an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per query structure, filters need to contain an array, so define filters as an array and directly push objects to it.

```
var filters = [];
for(var i in points){
  filters.push({"type":"EQ","fieldName":"name","value":points[i]}); 
}
var query = {"filters":{"type":"OR","filters":filters}};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could map the wanted object inside of the filters property.

```js
var points = ['Point_1', 'Point_2', 'Point_3'],
    query = { filters: { type: "OR", filters: points.map(function (p) {
        return { type: "EQ", fieldName: "name", value: p };
    }) } };

console.log(query);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```